# Rails - Have an image link to a controller's show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an image, and if it is clicked on, I would like the user to be redirected to my `MovieController#show` action

```
<ul>
  <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
    <li><%= link_to(movie_path(movie), image_tag "images.jpg", alt: "Movie 1"%)></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I tried something like the above, but I think I have the wrong idea.

I'm not sure how to combine `link_to` and `image_tag`, when I want the image to link to a specific item's show page.

I've used this page as a reference, but I can't figure anything out.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<%= link_to movie do %>
  <%= image_tag "images.jpg", alt: "Movie 1" %>
<% end %>
```